# Servir bibliotecas com CDN ou Servidor próprio?

Tags: javascript, css

Visando performance é mais performático utilizar uma `CDN` (que fornecem a versão completa e pricipal da biblioteca) ou distribuir versões de Bibliotecas Customizadas (ex: `jQuery UI` que fornece somente o efeito `accordion`). É possivel tambem meu site utilizar a `jQuery UI` baixada por outro site mesmo esta sendo diferente (completa e a minha custumizada tendo somente a função necessária)? Existe algum outro fator crucial?

Comment: Para bibliotecas customizadas, você pode usar a Amazon AWS. É quase de graça. http://aws.amazon.com/pt/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A principal função de um CDN para um desenvolvedor é não ter a preocupação de tráfego de rede e poder garantir aos visitantes sempre disponibilidade dos arquivos. Para o usuário é obter de um segundo domínio (carregamento paralelo) os arquivos, de um lugar que provavelmente estaria mais próximo fisicamente diminuindo a latência (tempo de conexão, resolução DNS e download).

Se o seus visitantes estão geograficamente próximos de você, ou são exclusivos de uma localidade (região do pais, pais ou continente) não existe MUITA necessidade de um CDN, pois para os usuários não fará tanta diferença. Neste caso, recomendo que você crie um subdomínio ou até mesmo um outro dominio (ai é estratégia sua) para servir esses arquivos. Assim você pode servir paralelamente e de um domínio "cookieless".

O ideal mesmo é você fazer com que suas páginas façam a menor quantidade possível de requisições (tanto para um mesmo domínio, quanto para vários: CDN, subdomínios, etc), assim você aumenta a velocidade de carregamento das páginas.

Tente juntar em apenas um arquivo .css ou .js (você pode desenvolver em arquivos separados, mas na hora de publicar junta tudo, ou utilize ferramentas que façam isso) todo o código que for ser utilizado por determinada área do seu site. Compacte (remova espaços desnecessários, indentações, comentários, utilize compressão GZIP) e forneça cache desses arquivos (configure para os arquivos ficarem no cache do usuário pelo maior tempo possível, e caso você atualize os dados nos arquivos, então mude a URL que o usuário busca, forçando um novo download, atualizado).

Se você vai fornecer personalização e está utilizando bibliotecas de scripts, não forneça a biblioteca de um CDN e sua personalização a parte do seu servidor (ou de seu CDN próprio). Junte tudo em apenas um e disponibilize tudo para seus usuários. Inicialmente você irá aumentar um pouco o tráfego do seu servidor, porém você irá diminuir as requisições por parte dos usuários e terá controle sobre o cache desses arquivos por completo.

Answer (score 4):

Cada estratégia tem seus prós e contras...

**CDN:** A grande vantagem é que grande parte dos usuários que caírem em seu site terão uma versão da biblioteca no cache. Isso reduz o tempo para download de recursos e o consumo de banda do seu site. As CDNs também tentam distribuir as bibliotecas a partir um servidor mais próximo do usuário, de maneira que, caso ele precise fazer o download de uma biblioteca, o fará com menos latência.

**Versão customizada**: Da primeira vez que seus usuários acessarem o site (e em iterações posteriores se ele não tiver mais a biblioteca em cache) terão que fazer download da biblioteca do seu servidor. A latência de um usuário distante pode ser alta, e isso consumirá a sua banda de upload. Por outro lado, você pode selecionar somente o que precisa de cada biblioteca (o que pode reduzir o tamanho do download, bem como o tempo de processamento / renderização).

> É possivel tambem meu site utilizar a jQuery UI baixada por outro site mesmo esta sendo diferente (completa e a minha custumizada tendo somente a função necessária)?

Não sei se entendi direito a pergunta, porém se você desenvolveu seu site em uma versão customizada (com apenas parte dos componentes), poderá trocar para a versão mais completa hospedada em uma CDN sem problemas. Quanto mais popular a CDN, menor a chance de um usuário ter que fazer o download da biblioteca.